# How to Receive parameter from GET on python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know Python very well; I have a program that works with the following command:

`python3 hello.py -word sometext -number 10`

Very well, everything is fine and running.
now,I want this program to work as a web service and take the parameters from the URL!
Like:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/?word=sometext&number=10`

i use socketserver to active listening port and it's work.**But I don't know how to get the parameters and run them in the program.**
I searched for hours and read a lot, but I didn't understand what to do.

Everything is simple in PHP:

```
$word = $_GET['word'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
```

I tried different methods with **urlparse **but it didn't work.

i found it:

```py
word= urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query).get('word', None)
print word
```

but But it was not what I thought.